# Is there a way to save a file I'm writing to in Java without using the .close() method?

Tags: java

I'm getting an input of ID numbers and writing each ID into the file as it is entered. The ID's written into the file are just a backup in case the program crashes for some reason (it's a small personal thing). So, if there's an unexpected shutdown, I'll just have a text file containing all of the ID numbers I've already entered. However, I'm noticing that the ID's don't get saved into the file until the .close() is executed when I manually close it, but that would just defeat the purpose.

This is my first time doing anything like this, so I'm not sure what the proper approach is. Is there some way to save the text without closing the BufferedWriter? Or is it acceptable to close it and open it right back up somehow?

Thank you for your suggestions!

Comment: You can try calling `flush()`.

Comment: Perfect! This was exactly it. I'm sorry for the simple question.

Comment: Instead of calling `flush()` everytime, you could do it based on on some count.. say for every 10 values... that would improve efficiency...

Comment: Thanks, but this is literally being done with like 100 values max. I'd improve efficiency for something larger, though!

Answer (score 5):

As stated by Elliott in the comments, `flush()` on a `BufferedWriter` will cause it to write to its destination. A `BufferedWriter` implements the [`Flushable` interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Flushable.html), whose javadoc states:

> The flush method is invoked to write any buffered output to the underlying stream.

Which is exactly what you needed

Answer (score 3):

You can use flush() method after writing to your BufferedWriter or if you do not want to bother about flushing then you can use PrintWriter and configure it using autoflush:

```
public PrintWriter(OutputStream out,
           boolean autoFlush)
```

> Creates a new PrintWriter from an existing OutputStream. This
>   convenience constructor creates the necessary intermediate
>   OutputStreamWriter, which will convert characters into bytes using the
>   default character encoding.
>
> Parameters:
>
> out - An output stream  autoFlush - A boolean; if true, the println,
>   printf, or format methods will flush the output buffer

hope this helps.